# A commutative ring with two non-zero ideals $I$ and $J$ such that $I \cap J = \{0\} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with two non-zero ideals $I$ and $J$ such that $I \cap J = \{0 \} $. What can we conclude about $R$ and the given ideals?

---

Can we say that $R$ is not a domain or it is finite? Is $R=I+J$? What about $I$ and $J$? Are they prime ideals of $R$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- $R$ can't be a domain. Indeed, as $I, J \neq 0$ you can find non-zero $i \in I$ and $j \in J$. Then you have that $ij \in I \cap J = \{0\}$. Hence $ij = 0$.
- $R$ isn't necessarily finite. Take $R = \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z [x]$ and let $I = 2R$ and $J = 3R$. Clearly we have that $I \cap J = \{0\}$.
- Not necessarily $R = I + J$. Again take $R = \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z[x]$ and let $I = 2R$, but this time $J = (3x)R$. I claim that $I+J \neq R$. Can you see why? What elements of $I+J$ look like? Why $1 \not \in I+J$
- $I$ and $J$ are not necessarily prime. Indeed you can take $R = \mathbb Z/36\mathbb Z$, $I = 9R$ and $J = 4R$